# jquery change event is calling three times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

i am calling a onchange function in my view. this field is picking date from calendar.

```
    $('#IDContractDate').on('change', function (e) {

        var GetThis = $(this).val();
        var CoveredId = $('#ddlCoveredIndividual option:selected').attr('attribute2');
        var relationshipId = $('#ddlCoveredIndividual option:selected').attr('code');

        if (CoveredId !== 'undefined' && relationshipId !== "undefined") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: AppVirtualPath + "MemberDetails/GetEnrollmentDates?personId=" + CoveredId + "&benefitOptionId=" + $('#hdBenefitOptionId').val() + "&benefitId=" + $('#hdBenefitId').val() + "&relationShipId=" + relationshipId + "&contractDate=" + GetThis,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        if (key == "SystemEntryDate") {
                            $('#IDsystemEntryDate').val(value);
                        }
                        else if (key == "EntryDate") {
                            $('#IDEntryDate').val(value);
                        }
                        else if (key == "ADCSDate") {
                            $('#IDADCStartDate').val(value);
                        }
                        else if (key == "NDCSDate") {
                            $('#IDNDCStartDate').val(value);
                        }
                    });

                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

i am not able to understand why this function is calling three times. please help..

Answer (score 1):

Handle your change event with this unbind() function. Hope this will make help to you.

```
$("#IDContractDate").unbind().on('change',function(e) {
    //Stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like handlers are getting attached multiple times. Unbind before hooking handler

```
$('#IDContractDate').unbind().on('change', function (e) {
});
```

Comment: i tried it and yes it stops multiple calls but then calendar is not working on this field.

Comment: With above code its difficult to say how the handler is adding multiple times. I am sure that in your code there is some issue. If you can show the full page code it could help